# Is there a way to flip four namest?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to put the last name and "," ahead of the first name and succeeding names.
I've managed to get it up to 3 names but now I have to account if the person has 4 names in their whole name. Mainly using this for Google Sheets.

Here's what I use for the 3 names.

```
=MID(TRIM(A2)&", "&TRIM(A2),IF(LEN(TRIM(A2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A2)," ",""))=1,FIND(" ",TRIM(A2))+1,FIND(" ",TRIM(A2),FIND(" ",TRIM(A2))+1)+1),LEN(TRIM(A2))+1)
```

so that turns "John Doe Smith" into "Smith, John Doe"

Anyone can help to account for 4 names?

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexreplace()`, like this:

```
=regexreplace(A2, "(.*) (\w+)", "$2, $1")
```

To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Answer (score 0):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(.*)\s(.*?)$","$2, $1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(\w+ \w+) (\w+)","$2, $1")
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as well as the other 2 answers. It turns 
John Doe Man Smith into Man Smith, John Doe. Though I might have a niche usecase for this so thanks as well :>

Comment: my bad, I misunderstood your request, you can just replace `(\w+ \w+)` with `(.+)` or `(.*)` which turns it into the same exact formula provided by doubleunary.